# Running Acumatica import scenario from code

Tags: import, acumatica

How to run select "Import by Scenario" scenario -> press "Prepare&Import" from code?

I have tried this:

```
var importGraph = PX.Data.PXGraph.CreateInstance<SYImportProcessSingle>();
SYMappingActive mapactive =  PXSelect<SYMappingActive>.Search<SYMappingActive.mappingID>(importGraph, importproviderID);
importGraph.PrepareImport.PressButton();
```

but this did not work to run "Prepare & Import" for "import by scenario" graph for my DAC.

Comment: I am getting "Provider not found" error

Comment: problem is i can not select correctly import scenario

Comment: alternative question is: "How to run SYImportProcess.RunScenario() properly"

Comment: Anybody please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check.  Can you execute the import scenario from the application instance?  I refer to the Process Import Scenario screen (SM206036).  The provider error could be that the import scenario has no data provider assigned, or the provider is not usable.

Comment: yes, i can execute import scenario from Process Import Scenario screen(SM206036) by pressing in browser button "Prepare & import" in browser.

Comment: in code it seems only need to run something like: SYImportProcess.RunScenario("imporSO") but it did not work

Comment: From the web services help article:  To execute an API call, you must build an array of commands and submit it to the form by calling the Submit() function. To process batch import and export operations, you define a scenario and use the Import() and Export() functions.  Look at the service description in the web service API, of your import scenario.

Comment: I am not using web services, i am creating customization project

Answer (score 0):

Here is example how you can do it. I have written this for SalesOrder but you can modify it for any other screen. Also if there exist more than one Import Scenario for the same screen this code will use first Active one.

```
public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    #region Actions
    public PXAction<SOOrder> RunScenario;

    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "RUN")]
    protected void runScenario()
    {
        var importGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SYImportProcessSingle>();
        var myMapping = PXSelect<SYMapping, Where<SYMapping.screenID, Equal<Required<SYMapping.screenID>>>>.Select(importGraph, Base.Accessinfo.ScreenID.Replace(".", string.Empty));
        if (myMapping.Any())
        {
            importGraph.MappingsSingle.Current = importGraph.MappingsSingle.Search<SYMappingActive.name>(((SYMapping)myMapping.First(x => ((SYMapping)x).IsActive ?? false)).Name);
            importGraph.Prepare.Press();
            PXLongOperation.WaitCompletion(importGraph.UID);
            importGraph.Clear(PXClearOption.ClearAll);
            importGraph.MappingsSingle.Current = importGraph.MappingsSingle.Search<SYMappingActive.name>(((SYMapping)myMapping.First(x => ((SYMapping)x).IsActive ?? false)).Name);
            importGraph.Import.Press();
            PXLongOperation.WaitCompletion(importGraph.UID);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```