# Is there a way to run an import scenario from inside a BLC?

Tags: acumatica

Is there a way to run / execute an import scenario from inside a BLC / Graph extension?  If so, could you provide a code example of how this would be done?

Thanks...

Comment: Check answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44024067/7376238

Comment: Wasn't checked as answered, so I assumed it was not correct.  Can I assume that it is correct?

Comment: It looks good, only way to confirm is to try it.